# Infinite loop - why?

Tags: php, loops, switch-statement, infinite

```
for($i=0; $i<5; $i++) {
    switch($i) {
        case 0:
            echo "<div class=\"darkgrey topdarkgrey\">";
            break;
        case 1:
        case 3:
            echo "<div class=\"lightgrey\">";
            break;
        case 2:
        case 4:
            echo "<div class=\"darkgrey\">";
            break;
        case 5:
            echo "<div class\"darkgrey bottomdarkgrey\">";
            break;
    }
    if($i=$idagInt) 
        echo "<div id=\"idag\">" . $dag[$i] . "<br>";
    else
        echo "<div class=\"dag\"><span class=\"veckoDag\">" . $dag[$i] . "</span><br>";

    echo "<span class=\"month\">" . $datumDay[$i] . " " . $month[$i] . "</span></div>";
    echo "<div class=\"mat\">" . strip_tags($mat[$i], "<p>") . "</div></div>";
}
```

This is the code I'm using to print things to the website and after some trouble-shooting my conclusion is that there's something wrong with the switch-statement, but I cant see what?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's your problem. You're assigning `$i` the value of `$idagInt` rather then comparing it. As a result `$i` never reaches 5.

```
if($i=$idagInt)
```

Change it to:

```
if($i==$idagInt)
```